# How to show the iOS lookup modal in Flutter for selected text?

Tags: flutter

In most iOS apps, selected text has a "lookup" option. Flutter interactive selection only shows "cut, copy and paste". I couldn't find an option for "lookup".

Is there a way to show the "lookup" option?

If not, assuming I create my own selection controls, is there a way to manually show the modal?

For reference, here's what I mean by "lookup" option:

[image]

and here's what I mean by the "lookup" modal:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cann't. Flutter overrides all the UI of the native system, drawing its own. Think in Flutter in the same way you think in a videogame. Flutter takes an OpenGL Canvas and draws all stuff by itself from scratch.

As you don't use any elements from native, you neither don't have the native contextual menus. That is why you get that different options.

Now, the kind of good news. You can modify the Flutter one to configure the options. You need to use the [SelectableText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText/SelectableText.html) widget from Flutter. Take a look also at the [selectionControls](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextSelectionControls-class.html) property. You can create your own toolbar from there.